# Remove value in one cell from string in another cell (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Where M2 is a string that appears as part of a longer string in S2, I need it purged from S2. So for instance, if M2 = "V90981" and S2 = "743827V90981FFUY", S2 needs to become "743827FFUY".

I've looked at using VB's Replace function, but I couldn't figure out how to make the search term for each row variable based on the value in another column. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, to specifically purge the contents of S2 with m2, you could use something like:

```
[s2].Replace what:=[m2], replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart
```

If you want to cycle through a range of rows, you could do something like:

```
Dim rLongString As Range
Dim rShortString As Range
Dim I As Long

Set rLongString = Range("S2:S10")
Set rShortString = Range("M2:M10")

For I = 1 To rLongString.Count
    rLongString(I).Replace what:=rShortString(I), replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart
Next I
```